# How can I write to a file using BufferedWriter if the input type is double?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, bufferedwriter, filehandle

I am trying to write to a file using `BufferedWriter`. As the write method takes `int` argument, I am casting input of `double` type into `int` type but it is not being written properly into the file.

```java
try{
     Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("/home/amit/Desktop/number.csv"));
     file.useDelimiter(", *");
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/amit/Desktop/output_number.csv"));
      while(file.hasNextDouble()){
           writer.write((int)(file.nextDouble()));
      }
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
    }catch(Exception x){
            x.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried reading the input as `int` that, `file.nextInt()` but it does not work either.

Comment: Can you show the desired output vs produced output? Casting `double` to `int` truncates the decimal part.

Comment: If you're writing various primitives and strings, perhaps it would make more sense to use [DateOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) (and `DataInputStream` for reading).

Comment: Why do you even parse the input to a double when you’re going to reproduce the same text? Simply using `writer.write(file.next());` would do. Besides that, you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedWriter` cannot write `doubles`, see the [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-). However, you can convert your `double (file.nextDouble())` into a `String`, for instance using `Double.toString((file.nextDouble()))` and then write the resulting string with `write(String)`.